# Join to subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

q1:

```
 SELECT SUBSTR(o.first_name,1,1)||' '||o.last_name "NAME",
    FROM employees o
    WHERE o.salary >
    (SELECT AVG(i.salary)
    FROM employees i
    WHERE i.department_id =
    o.department_id)
```

I have a department table with department_id and department_name  || how to join it to this result to display  the results of the subquery and dep name ?

q2)this throws an error , after adding the last line : why?

```
SELECT SUBSTR(first_name, 1, 1) || ' ' || last_name "Employee Name", department_id "Department Id", to_char(NULL) "Department Name", to_char(NULL) " City" 
FROM employees
UNION
SELECT to_char(NULL) "Employee Name" , department_id "Department ID", department_name "Department Name", to_char(NULL)" City" 
FROM departments
UNION 
SELECT to_char(NULL) "Employee Name" , to_char(NULL) "Department Id", to_char(NULL) "Department Name" ,to_char(NULL )"City"
FROM locations
```

Comment: For the error, please add the error you are getting. As for your query, if you add your table structure and some sample data, maybe we can help you achieve this in a better way. As for the

Comment: @Filipe: error :ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression.. the table i would like to join to into q2 has department_id, department_name..

Comment: the first one i have no clue how to approach to get three columns: the name and salary (from subquery) and dep name from the other table

Answer (score 1):

For your first query try:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(o.first_name, 1, 1) || ' ' || o.last_name "NAME",
  d.department_name "DEP NAME"
FROM employees o
INNER JOIN department d ON d.department_id = o.department_id
WHERE o.salary > (
    SELECT AVG(i.salary)
    FROM employees i
    WHERE i.department_id = o.department_id
    )
```

Your error comes most likely from having `to_char(null)` for `department_id` when this column isn't a CHAR.

Just use `null` instead:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(first_name, 1, 1) || ' ' || last_name "Employee Name",
  department_id "Department Id",
  to_char(NULL) "Department Name",
  to_char(NULL) " City"
FROM employees    
UNION    
SELECT to_char(NULL) "Employee Name",
  department_id "Department ID",
  department_name "Department Name",
  to_char(NULL) " City"
FROM departments    
UNION    
SELECT to_char(NULL) "Employee Name",
  NULL "Department Id",     -- Replace to_char(null) with NULL
  to_char(NULL) "Department Name",
  city_name "City"    -- Add city_name column to get results different than NULL
FROM locations
```

Comment: Why is `TO_CHAR` needed at all?

Comment: Although the error is gone, there hase to be a logical error, since as last , city names should be displayed, and there arent any in the list.--UPDATE: corrected to_char(NULL) "City" to city "city. works perfect. thanks!

Comment: @PM77-1. I'm not sure what is the reason for him to use it. I just pointed out what was most likely giving him that error.

Comment: @user3026370. there is an error for sure. You have always to_char(null) in every select for City. You might want to add the city_name(i assume) to the last query's "City" column

Comment: @user3026370. I added an attempt to answer your first problem. See if it is what you were loking for.

Comment: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist for the first one

Comment: Yes, Filipe : the problem was the table name, after updating the name it works.obrigado!/beer on me:)

Comment: If this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted. ([here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) on how that works).